# Change output color of terminal (in Mac) to be different from typed text color

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, color, themes

I know how to change the color of ls output, but I would like to change the color of all terminal output.

To make clear what I mean, below is a picture of my terminal. My text color is orange.

However, I would want the `-bash: p: command not found`, `test`, and the output of `df` to be a different color, so that it is easier to see the difference between what I type. Is this possible?

[image]

---

This is how it looks with @jmhindle answer. You can change the number after setaf for a different color (e.g. 2 for green).

[image]

Comment: How did you set the Blue and Green text in your screenshots?

Comment: This is so long ago I don't remember, sorry

Comment: FYI for any other [oh-my-bash](https://ohmybash.nntoan.com/) users: you can just customize your PS1 shell prompt by following [these instructions](https://github.com/ohmybash/oh-my-bash/wiki/Customization)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can do this by installing a DEBUG trap in ~/.bash_profile.

See the answer to [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/175799/does-bash-have-a-hook-that-is-run-before-executing-a-command).

I added the following:

```
preexec() { 
    tput setaf 4
    :
}
preexec_invoke_exec() {
    [ -n "$COMP_LINE" ] && return
    local this_command=`HISTTIMEFORMATE= history 1 | sed -e "s/^[ ]*[0-9]*[ ]*//"`;
    preexec "$this_command"
}

trap 'preexec_invoke_exec' DEBUG
```

`tput setaf 4` changes foreground colour to blue.

Comment: Thanks! I'll update my question to include how it looks now

Comment: `while :; do [ "${i:=0}" -lt 8 ] || i=0; tput setaf "$i"; sleep .5; : "$((i++))"; done &`  A good (and non-destructive) prank.  ;)  (To get rid of it—`kill %1` followed by `tput setaf 7`.)

Comment: For me this is changing all of the text color in terminal, both typed text and output.